# Why can't I display mysql data in textbox?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, textbox

I write a code in Visual Studio 2010 which creates a new table in my database.
Later I can't read those values into `textboxes` because the error message says:

> *There are NULL values in the table and can't read it.*

But I want to see those `Null` values in empty `textboxes`, because I like to upgrade those later with values.
Why  this happening? Can you help me?

But when I create a table in MySql the program is OK. Where I see Null values=empty textboxes in form.
My code is:

```
 string strCreate = "CREATE TABLE `dbname`.`tablename` (`id` INT NOT NULL,`name` VARCHAR(45) NULL, `gender` VARCHAR(45) NULL,`adresse` VARCHAR(45) NULL), PRIMARY KEY (`id`))";
```

Comment: A bit of code would be helpfull

Comment: Is there some reason that prevents you from checking if the values are null in your database and if they are setting your Text to an empty string?

Answer (score 3):

You could check if the column in a row is null by using IsNull():

```
 Textbox1.Text = row.IsNull("columnName") ? "" : row["columnName"];
```

Or you could use DBNull.Value:

```
 Textbox1.Text = row["columnName"]==DBNull.Value ? "" : row["columnName"];
```